# Proof that the function $f(x)=x(\frac{3}{2}+\lfloor -x^2 \rfloor)$ is injective

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've been stuck on this one for a while, what I've basically tried is showing that:
$$ f(x) = f(y)\ \ \Longrightarrow\ \ x = y$$
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

We can show $f$ is injective by the $3$ observations below:

- As $x>1$ increases, $\lfloor-x^2\rfloor\leq-2$ is decreasing, thus $f(x)>-1/2$ is strictly decreasing as $x>1$ increases.
- As $x<-1$ decreases, $\lfloor-x^2\rfloor\leq-2$ is decreasing, thus $f(x)>1/2$ is strictly increasing as $x<-1$ decreases.
- For $|x|\leq1$, we have $\lfloor-x^2\rfloor=-1$, so $f(x)=x/2\in[-1/2,1/2]$.

Here is a [Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/njcvlm8zwf) to help understand this argument.

Comment: I really wanted to prove it using my method. anyways, thanks.

Comment: @MBM You are welcome, and could you include what your method is in the question so we can help you better? Thank you.

Comment: if f(x) = f(y) and x≠y, you reach: $\frac{1}{2}(x-y)=x\lfloor x^2 \rfloor-y\lfloor y^2 \rfloor$. I just need to proof that no real x and y can be found as such.

Comment: @MBM The purpose of the $3$ observations is just to help us prove no $x$ and $y$ can be found as such in your comment. This is because if $f$ is strictly increasing then $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ (this is due to $f(x)>f(y)$ for $x>y$ and $f(x)<f(y)$ for $x<y$). Similarly if $f$ is strictly decreasing.